# cross-browser solution for three equal-distant logos at the top of the page

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have 3 logos in my website. The requirements are:

- The first should be at the top left.
- a second that should be at the top right.
- a third that should in the middle of the two logos in equal distance from them.

I am not expert in CSS, and I did my best but to no avail. I managed to make the the two first logos float in right and left, but for the third, i am using `margin`  and `absolute position`, which is not a good solution as I think: when resizing the browser or changing device or browser, it has a bad position.

The code I am using:

```
<img src="images/logo2.png" width="150" height="215" style="float:right">
<img src="images/logo3.png"  height="70" style="margin:10px 620px 10px 0; position: absolute">
<img src="images/logo1.png" width="133" height="235" style=" float:left;">
```

Please to help me find a solution for this issue, It will be highly appreciated.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <img src="images/logo2.png" width="150" height="215" style="float:right">
  <img src="images/logo3.png"  height="70" >
  <img src="images/logo1.png" width="133" height="235" style=" float:left;">
</div>
```

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pszna/1/)

This should work as long as the sum of the image widths is smaller than the body width.

Otherwise you should use percentage values for the image widths like done [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Pszna/2/).

Comment: It is working. thank you very much for your quick and smart help

Comment: The last remark you provided is very important, how can I set the width of image according to device. Using percentage???

Comment: @Sirko please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176600/stricter-kbd-formatting-disallow-jsfiddle-links-and-other-non-kbd-content-fro and remove the `kbd` tag from that link..

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces See [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pszna/2/). Percentages should work fine.

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces What do you mean?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29037/discussion-between-sirko-and-whiteletters-and-blankspaces)